# How to use jQuery in WordPress 5.7+

Tags: jquery

If jQuery is included in WordPress, why do I get 'jQuery is undefined' errors?
I cannot find a tutorial (one would think this would be in the WordPress docs) on how to use jQuery in modern versions of WordPress (I'm using 5.7). Do I need to enqueue anything? Deregister anything? Do anything in functions.php. I've tried:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
(function($) {
```

Is there documentation anywhere that explains the basic methods of using jQuery in my WordPress code? Everything I can find on the Interwebs is old or doesn't solve the issue.

Thanks.

UPDATE (per Jos Faber's recommendation), but still getting undefined error:

```
function hs_load_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hs_load_scripts');
```

```
<script>
    const $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(function() {

        $('#servers').on('submit', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_url, 
                ...
```

Comment: You need to enqueue `jquery`. That's always been the case.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script` is actually special where you can do it on the fly as well I think. Rather than `wp_enqueue_style`, which should be included in an action am

Answer (score 2):

(I'm using 5.7.2) This is all you have to use: `const $ = jQuery.noConflict();`. However, you have to make sure the file you load is loaded after jQuery to prevent timing issues. So either make jQuery a dependency of your script like this:

```
function _jf_load_scripts()
{
        wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/build/js/main.bundle.js', array('jquery'), MY_VERSION, TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('main');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_jf_load_scripts');
```

Or enqueue jQuery upfront, like this:

```
function _jf_load_scripts()
{
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/build/js/main.bundle.js', array(), MY_VERSION, TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('main');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_jf_load_scripts');
```

When your scripts load after jQuery, any of the used methods you describe above should work.

Comment: I enqueued upfront like you suggested. The jQuery code is on the actual php/html page so no need to reference an external file. Still getting the errors so see my update above to see what I'm doing. So strange, I have jQuery running on multiple sites, it's just this one that is not working.

Comment: Might still be a timing issue. If jQuery is not available, it's probably not loaded yet. 
You could try to check with an interval: `setInterval(() => console.log($ || 'not available'), 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

I hate to admit this (I'm might get thrown off StackExchange for being such a dolt). Turns out...drum roll...I forgot `get_header()` on my page. No header, no nothing.